# Passing data from parent class to child function -props undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data 'template_titles' to my child component and display them in an option dropdown. Just trying to console.log the data to make sure it's passing. Currently running into an issue where property props are undefined.

Parent Component

```
    render() {
    if (!this.props.show) {
        return null;
    }

    const template_titles = this.state.email_template.map((a) => a.title);
    console.log(template_titles);

    return (
        <div className='compose-email'>
            <div className='directory'>
                <div className='background' />
                <div className='box'>
                    <ion-icon
                        id='close-email'
                        name='close'
                        onClick={this.onClose}
                    ></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon
                        id='square-email'
                        name='square'
                        onClick={this.onClose}
                    ></ion-icon>
                    <h1 className='candidate-name-compose-email'>
                        Candidate Name
                    </h1>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <h1 className='compose-email-title-compose-email'>
                        Compose Email
                    </h1>
                    <ComposeEmailForm
                        handleCompose={this.sendNewEmail}
                        template_titles={this.template_titles}
                    />
                </div>
                <ToastContainer className='toast-container' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Child Component

```
    export default function ComposeEmailForm({ handleCompose }) {

console.log(this.props.template_titles);

return (
    <div className='container'></div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
export default function ComposeEmailForm({ handleCompose, template_titles }) {

console.log(template_titles);

return (
    <div className='container'></div>
);
```

You can't use `this` when your component is a function and not a class.

And when passing it, you need to drop the `this` too:

```
 <ComposeEmailForm
    handleCompose={this.sendNewEmail}
    template_titles={template_titles}
 />
```

since you define it as such in your `render` function.

Comment: Currently logs template_titles of undefined. which should display an array of data. edit: FIXED I needed to change {this.template_titles} to {template_titles}

Comment: Just edited my answer to address your other issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the function component, you don't too use `this`, especially when you destruct `props` in the parentheses of the argument, then you can access to you props like below:

```
export default function ComposeEmailForm({ handleCompose, template_titles }) {

  console.log(template_titles, handleCompose);

  return (
    <div className='container'></div>
  );
};
```